# Do I have to destroy SESSION when user logs out?

Tags: php, session

I only store logged users id in SESSION.

When a user logs out, SESSION becomes useless for me. Do I have to destroy it?

These are the methods of Utils class which I am using to start and destroy SESSION.

```
static function sessionSecureStart()
{
    if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
        session_start();
    }
}

static function sessionSecureDestroy()
{

    //Utils::sessionSecureStart(); This part is for testing only

    if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) {
        $_SESSION = [];
        session_destroy();
    }

}
```

Sometimes randomly I get errors/warnings like `SESSION could not be destroyed....` Am I doing something wrong?

(I am using PHP/5.5.25)

Comment: Can you expand upon (and provide the exact text of) the errors/warnings?

Comment: @user2864740 I try to catch the error text to post here. But as I said it is random. Sometimes while refreshing page. For example after 5 refresh without any interaction.  I will update my question when I get it again.

Comment: To me, that 'random error' is the *real* issue.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to destroy the whole session, just `unset` the parts you don't need. Let's say that when a user logs in that you set `$_SESSION['user_id']` and everything that says **I am logged in** is looking for that variable. A simple `unset($_SESSION['user_id']);` and suddenly the user is logged out. Remember, your user doesn't have control over what's in the session.

Another option is to [set the session cookies to very low lifetimes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php). It's cruder but just as effective.

Answer (score 0):

I highly advice you to destroy the session. For both security and performance.

Normally session data is saved in temporary files on the server and in a cookie on the browser, this one only contains the session id but no data.

When you call session destroy you delete this file but you also might tel the browser to delete the session cookie (sending a cookie with the same name which expires in the past). You can know the name calling the `session_name()` function (normally it's `PHPSESSID`).

Answer (score 0):

> When a user logs out, SESSION becomes useless for me. Do I have to destroy it?

Yes. Besides destroying it, it's also helpful to generate a new session-id

> Sometimes randomly I get errors/warnings like SESSION could not be destroyed.... Am I doing something wrong?

You cannot destroy a session that haven't been started. Make sure you have successfully initiated your sessions with `session_start();` before trying to destroy it